# SBCL initialization file

Tags: emacs, lisp, sbcl

I would like to know where I should save my .sbclrc file.  I tried saving it in my .sbcl folder, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm using Windows XP with Emacs version 23.

I'm trying to set up asdf-install, that is why I'm mucking around with the initialization file.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: On Linux the .sbclrc file goes in the user's home directory.  I'm not sure what the equivalent directory on windows is, perhaps your user's entry in the "Documents and Settings" folder (I think on windows that's where different users are differentiated but I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What is the result of evaluating this in the repl:

```
(SB-IMPL::USERINIT-PATHNAME)
```