# autoload forms after loading SBCL

Tags: windows, common-lisp, sbcl

How can I load forms to SBCL automatically after SBCL has loaded? I have a project that I'm constantly working on, and need to reproduce the loading steps every time.

I can't find .sbclrc file at the `(SB-IMPL::USERINIT-PATHNAME)` location (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245854/sbcl-initialization-file)), and even if I create it, it just does nothing.

Comment: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Initialization-Files
If you did everything right and it does not work, you might want to ask on the SBCL mailing list for help and see if it is a bug.

Comment: Does [Running a Common Lisp function from a Terminal command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20301668/1281433) help?  It includes discussion of the `--load` and `--eval` options, and I think that one of those two would work for you.

Comment: @hajovonta why not putting the bootstrapping/initialization code to some file (e.g. setup-dev-env.lisp) and load it after SBCL starting. Comapring to .sbclrc approach (which btw works for me) it will cost you one "manual" file loading, but it's more flexible (e.g. you can have several setup files for various situations and/or projects).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I ended up using --load option, which completely fits for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you for your responses. I ended up using `--load` option, which
>   completely fits for me. –  hajovonta